# bootstrap skips rapidly from col-lg to col-xs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a problem with structuring my bootstrap grid. I ve set it to 48 columns.
I have made a layout with col-lg and after that I started resizing the screen. I was so surprised when it turned out that the layout unlike with Bootstrap 2.2 skips rapidly from col-lg to col-xs ommiting col-md and col-sm. Do you know how to make it resize slowly through all resolutions as it was prevously in bootstrap 2.2 ? 
Here is the sample code:

```
    <menu class="row menu-regular">
            <div class="col-lg-2">&nbsp;</div>
            <figure class="">
                <img src="images/empflow_white.svg" class="col-lg-10">
            </figure>
            <div class="col-lg-8 empty">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4  pa t20x">About</div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 empty">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3  pa t20x">Pricing</div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 empty">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 pa t20x contact-right-border">Contact</div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 empty">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3  pa t20x">Log in</div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 empty">&nbsp;</div>
            <button class="col-lg-6 pa t12x register-button tac p10x">Register</button>
            <div class="col-lg-2">&nbsp;</div>
       </menu>
```

Comment: "If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line."

Comment: If you want the layout to change depending on the size of the screen, you have to define that in the HTML. Currently you only have the "large" screen layout configured, so what you are experiencing is the expected result.

Comment: Like what @j08691 said, you have way too many columns. They need to equal out to 12 in a .row div. Also specify the col-xs col-sm and col-md classes on each, not just col-lg

Comment: Ok, thank all of You for the tips.